# Etherpad lite not loading on firefox

Tags: etherpad

Etherpad lite is not loading on Firefox, it works on other browsers and also works on Firefox private window.

On Firefox it just shows 'loading...'.

I get the following error:

```
UserAgent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:30.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/30.0
TypeError: pad.collabClient is null in http://hostname.com/javascripts/lib/ep_etherpad-lite/static/js/pad.js?callback=require.define at line 3'
```

How do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Do you experience that on all Etherpad instances?  It's worth noting Etherpad Lite is now called Etherpad, the lite part was dropped ages ago..

Try out http://beta.etherpad.org